# Encrypt and garble audio file using JAVA

Tags: java, audio, encryption, mp3, des

I'm currently working on a project to encrypt MP3 audio using JAVA and produce garbled sound from that encrypted MP3 file. So far, I can encrypt the whole MP3 file using DES encryption method. However, this encrypted file is not playable using MP3 player. I know that MP3 file has some structure (header and data, etc), but I have no idea to implement encryption on this file without breaking the whole MP3 structure.

How to make this encrypted MP3 file playable?

Comment: I did a similar thing for MPEG-2 transport streams many years ago - encrypt the picture and audio data, but leave the MPEG structures in place so that other equipment (such as a utility to extract all the I frames) could still manipulate the file.  However, I'm afraid this isn't quite a specific enough problem for SO to answer.  I think you know the answer anyway: you need to pick apart the stream and only encrypt the actual audio data ...

Comment: Yep, I think that's the main problem : to extract the actual audio data using JAVA program. I wonder if there is such program in JAVA...Thanks for your response anyway...

Comment: Why are you using DES?  It is slow and obsolete.  Use AES instead.  If you don't need authentication then use AES-CTR or AES-CBC.  If you do need authentication then use AES-GCM.

Answer (score 1):

Some more info about parsing and mp3 stream in java: [JavaLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) is an mp3 decoder that naturally implements stream processing mostly with `javazoom.jl.decoder.Bitstream` class. It will skip all tag data and give you raw bytes for each frame.

Another library that does some mp3 stream parsing is [jaudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/), maybe you can scavenge some code from there too.

Both of these libraries are distributed under LGPL, so just be aware of licensing issues.